# Define new hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

I want to define hyphenation for a word I have somewhat created.

I have a word that I have hyphenated like

```
com\-.puppy\-crawl\-.tools\-.check\-style\-.api
```

The thing is that every time I want to use that word I have to write everything, including the `\-`. Is there a way for me to define hyphenation for a word and be able to use it through out the document?

Comment: Do you write it as `\url{...}`?

Comment: I have it like `\texttt{...}`

Comment: Use `\url` then there is a possible linebreak at the dot by default.

Comment: This didn't quite hyphenated the word. It did line break it, but it's note the samething, besides that is not an URL.

Comment: It is a bit curious to hyphenate a program path ... because nobody knows if the hyphen is part of the path or not.

Comment: This is a Java package definition. I guess you are right, but with `\url` it turned the whole word into a link, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @Tiago: `\nolinkurl{...}`

Comment: Great. Thanks Herbert. I'm not sure I have placed my question appropriately so you could make this an answer so I could mark it as correct, but I have up voted your comments.

Comment: @Tiago: I added it as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It makes more sense to use `\url{..}` for Java package names. If you use `hyperref` and do not want it as a link, then use `nolinkurl{...}`.  Urls can have a line break at the dot by default.

Comment: I assume you mean "do not want" and "dot".

Answer (score 9):

well, `\hyphenation{...}` won't work since there are non-letters in the string.
probably the most direct approach is to just define a shorthand command that includes
all the discretionary hyphens:
`\newcommand\compuppy{com\-.puppy\-crawl\-.tools\-.check\-style\-.apl}`
you might want to finish it off with `\xspace` to avoid having to remember to finish
it off with a backslash before a space.

Comment: the xspace thing didn't work. `\newcommand\compuppy{\texttt{com\-.puppy\-crawl\-.tools\-.check\-style\-.api}\xspace}
` Am I using it right?

Comment: @Tiago You need `\usepackage{xspace}`, otherwise it is used correctly.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So far this is the best answer, but Herbert has indeed raised a good question on the comments.