# Hyphenation not working as expected

Tags: hyphenation

I have the following text:

```
The example shown in figure \ref{fg:package_normal} shows the scope of the class \textit{org.\-argouml.\-kernel.\-ProfileConfiguration} (\textit{Having}).
```

Unfortunately the name ProfileConfiguration is so long that it is longer than the textwidth. That's why I added those `\-` to indicate that it should be hyphenated earlier. But this does not work. So how can I correct it?

### EDIT

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[formal]{seal_thesis}
\begin{document}
The example shown in figure \ref{fg:package_normal} shows the scope of the class \textit{org.\-argouml.\-kernel.\-ProfileConfiguration} (\textit{Having}).

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

And here is the template:

```
%%
%% This is file `seal_thesis.cls'.
%%
%% This file is the seal thesis class files. All thesis at seal should
%% be written using this style file.
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{seal_thesis}
              [2005/02/10 v1.0e
 seal LaTeX thesis class]

\LoadClass[10pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\newif\ifformal
\formalfalse

\DeclareOption{formal}{%
\formaltrue
}
\ProcessOptions
% Using Palatino font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{21.3cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-6mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{4mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection \ \ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\small\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\def\thesisType#1{\gdef\@thesisType{#1}}
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\home#1{\gdef\@home{#1}}
\def\country#1{\gdef\@country{#1}}
\def\legi#1{\gdef\@legi{#1}}
\def\prof#1{\gdef\@prof{#1}}
\def\assistent#1{\gdef\@assistent{#1}}
\def\email#1{\gdef\@email{#1}}
\def\url#1{\gdef\@url{#1}}
\def\begindate#1{\gdef\@begindate{#1}}
\def\enddate#1{\gdef\@enddate{#1}}

\gdef\@thesisType{No Thesis Type given}
\gdef\@title{No Title given}
\gdef\@subtitle{missing}
\gdef\@date{No Date given}
\gdef\@home{No Home given}
\gdef\@country{No Country given}
\gdef\@legi{No Legi given}
\gdef\@prof{No Professor given}
\gdef\@assistent{No Assisten(s) given}
\gdef\@email{missing}
\gdef\@url{missing}
\gdef\@begindate{No Begin Date given}
\gdef\@enddate{No End Date given}
\def\missing{missing}

\newif\ifsubtitle
\subtitletrue
\newif\ifemail
\emailtrue
\newif\ifurl
\urltrue

\newlength{\normaltopmargin}
\setlength\normaltopmargin{\topmargin}

\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \ifformal
  \ifx\@subtitle\missing
    \subtitlefalse
  \fi
  \ifx\@email\missing
    \emailfalse
  \fi
  \ifx\@url\missing
    \urlfalse
  \fi
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begingroup
  \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont
  \begin{flushright}%
    \vspace*{50\p@}
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@thesisType}
    \vskip -9\p@
    \vbox{\hrule height0.25pt width\textwidth}
    \vskip -2\p@
    {\fontsize{9}{0}\selectfont \@date}
    \vskip 20\p@
    {\fontfamily{pfr}\fontsize{48}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@title}
    \ifsubtitle
      \vskip 5\p@
      {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@subtitle}
    \fi
    \vfill
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@author}
    \vskip -2\p@
    {\fontsize{9}{0}\selectfont of \@home,\ \@country \ (\@legi)}
    \vskip 35\p@
    {\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\bfseries supervised by}
    \vskip 4\p@
    {\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont \@prof\\[2\p@] \@assistent}
 \end{flushright}%
 \vskip 87\p@
 \parindent \z@
 \includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo_inf}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{seal_bw}
 \endgroup
 \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begingroup
  \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont
  \begin{flushright}%
    \vspace*{50\p@}
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@thesisType}
    \vskip -9\p@
    \vbox{\hrule height0.25pt width\textwidth}
    \vskip 31\p@
    {\fontsize{48}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@title}
    \ifsubtitle
      \vskip 5\p@
      {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@subtitle}
    \fi
    \vfill
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@author}
 \end{flushright}%
 \vskip 174\p@
 \parindent \z@
 \includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo_inf}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{seal_bw}
 \endgroup
 \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
 \normalfont
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \noindent
 \hspace{-0.9em}
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
   {\bf \@thesisType} & \\[4\p@]
   {\bf Author:} & \@author \ifemail , \@email\fi\\[4\p@]
   \ifurl
   {\bf URL:} & \@url \\[4\p@]
   \fi
   {\bf Project period:} & \@begindate \ - \@enddate \\[4\p@]
 \end{tabular}

 \vskip 4\p@
 \noindent Software Evolution \& Architecture Lab\\[2\p@]
 \noindent Department of Informatics, University of Zurich%
}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begingroup
  \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont
  \begin{flushright}%
    \vspace*{50\p@}
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@thesisType}
    \vskip -9\p@
    \vbox{\hrule height0.25pt width\textwidth}
    \vskip -2\p@
    {\fontsize{9}{0}\selectfont \@date}
    \vskip 20\p@
    {\fontsize{48}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@title}
    \ifsubtitle
      \vskip 5\p@
      {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@subtitle}
    \fi
    \vfill
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@author}
    \vskip -2\p@
    {\fontsize{9}{0}\selectfont of \@home,\ \@country \ (\@legi)}
    \vskip 35\p@
    {\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\bfseries supervised by}
    \vskip 4\p@
    {\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont \@prof\\[2\p@] \@assistent}
 \end{flushright}%
 \vskip 87\p@
 \parindent \z@
 \includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo_inf}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{seal_bw}
 \endgroup
 \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begingroup
  \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont
  \begin{flushright}%
    \vspace*{50\p@}
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@thesisType}
    \vskip -9\p@
    \vbox{\hrule height0.25pt width\textwidth}
    \vskip 31\p@
    {\fontsize{48}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@title}
    \ifsubtitle
      \vskip 5\p@
      {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont \@subtitle}
    \fi
    \vfill
    {\fontsize{24}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@author}
 \end{flushright}%
 \vskip 174\p@
 \parindent \z@
 \includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo_inf}\hfill\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{seal_bw}
 \endgroup
 \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
 \normalfont
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \noindent
 \hspace{-0.9em}
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
   {\bf \@thesisType} & \\[4\p@]
   {\bf Author:} & \@author \ifemail , \@email\fi\\[4\p@]
   \ifurl
   {\bf URL:} & \@url \\[4\p@]
   \fi
   {\bf Project period:} & \@begindate \ - \@enddate \\[4\p@]
 \end{tabular}

 \vskip 4\p@
 \noindent Software Evolution \& Architecture Lab\\[2\p@]
 \noindent Department of Informatics, University of Zurich
}

%\def\ps@sealheadings{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
%       \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
%       \let\@mkboth\markboth
%   \def\@evenhead{\vbox{\hbox
%       {\llap{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\bfseries\thepage}}\hfil
%       {\rlap{\parbox[b]{50pt}{\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\leftmark}}}}
%         \hrule height0.4pt width\textwidth}}
%   \def\@oddhead{\vbox{\hbox to \textwidth{%
%         \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont{\rightmark}\hfil\bfseries\thepage}\vskip 1.5pt plus 0pt minus 1.5pt%
%         \hrule height0.4pt width\textwidth}}
%   \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth{\@chapapp \ \thechapter.\ \ ##1}{}}%
%   \def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\thesection \ \ ##1}}}

%\ps@fancyheadings

\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright
                        \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
                    \else
                        \clearpage
                    \fi
                    \thispagestyle{empty}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \hfill{\fontfamily{pfr}\fontsize{22}{0}\selectfont\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}%
        \par\nobreak
        \vbox{\hrule height0.25pt width\textwidth}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \flushright{\fontfamily{pfr}\fontsize{32}{0}\selectfont\bfseries #1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vbox{\hrule height0.4pt width\textwidth}
    \flushright{\fontfamily{pfr}\fontsize{32}{0}\selectfont\bfseries #1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.8ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\LARGE\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.3ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.3ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny\raisebox{1.5pt}{$\m@th\bullet$}}

%%\def\fnum@figure{{\bfseries\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont %%\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}}
%%\def\fnum@table{{\bfseries\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont %%\tablename\nobreakspace\thetable}}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{{\bfseries\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont{#1}}: \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont{#2}}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    {\bfseries\fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont{#1}}: \fontfamily{pfr}\selectfont{#2}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\box\@tempboxa}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

% new contenttable for lists and tables
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \newpage
    \section*{\listfigurename}
        \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \section*{\listtablename}
        \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{%
    \section*{List of \lstlistlistingname}
        \@starttoc{lol}%
}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}

\newenvironment{abstract}{%
  \chapter*{Abstract}}
  {}

\newenvironment{zusammenfassung}{%
  \chapter*{Zusammenfassung}}{}

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
  \chapter*{Acknowledgements}}{}


\endinput
```

Comment: It works for me. You need to include a complete example.

Comment: Yes maybe it is because of the template and the indention at the start of the line. I'll see that I can create an example.

Comment: @Lev Bishop I added a complete example, but how can I also include the template?

Comment: See the answers to [Define new hyphenation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12222/define-new-hyphenation). I think using `\url` together with `\urlstyle{it}` could give you better hyphenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either rephrase the sentence or locally increase the tolerance for the problematic paragraph. This will enable LaTeX to hyphenate at the hyphenation points you set and not make an overful line. However, it will not look optimal.

```
{\tolerance=10000 The example shown in
figure \ref{fg:package_normal} shows
the scope of the class
\textit{org.\-argouml.\-kernel.\-ProfileConfiguration}
(\textit{Having}).\par}
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Then I'll will prefer to rephrase it.